# MVC text not evaluating HTML within text

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have some text within a table that I am currently using a Html.DisplayFor to show. Many of the text items contain HTML elements such as list items and bold however when displaying this text on screen it is not converting these but instead simply displaying them as plain text, for example:

```
"Case moved from <b>123</b> to <b>456</b>"
```

Rather than

"Case moved from **123** to **456**"

Is there a HTML helper I can use out of the box to achieve what I'm after, or do I need to write my own extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Html.Raw()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx) method as suggested by Stephen Muecke in comments.

> Returns markup that is not HTML encoded.